# echo multiple values from mysql table

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, echo

I'm running out of ideas on how to do this.  I have a table with memberOrders.  Right now there are three entries.  I don't have a problem displaying it on the screen, I have a problem with PLACING it on the screen.  I need to put it 600px from the top.  And it has to be within an echo statement because it's looking through the rows within a while loop for the same memberNumber and then displaying all of the rows on the screen.  But when I do it in an echo statement and place the table 600 down on the screen, it places ALL the rows on top of each other and I'm out of ideas how to separate them.  Here's what I have:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Must start session first thing
//Connect to the database through our include 
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
// Place Session variable 'id' into local variable
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
// Process the form if it is submitted
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT memberNumber FROM members WHERE id='$userid'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$uniqueMember = $row['memberNumber'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memberOrders WHERE memberNumber='$uniqueMember'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<table cellpadding="12" style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:600px">
            <tr style="border:1px solid black">
              <th style="padding:15px">Link To Order</th>
              <th>Order Cost</th>
              <th>Order Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>',$row['orderLinks'],'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center">$',$row['cost'],'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center">',$row['orderStatus'],'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>',"<br>";
}
?>
```

I know the code is not perfect and it's messy but I just want to display everything in a nice table format with three or four table headers and the results under the headers without them going on top of each other.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are echoing the table with every entry. You need to put the table and header row before the loop:

```
echo '<table cellpadding="12" style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:600px">
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
          <th style="padding:15px">Link To Order</th>
          <th>Order Cost</th>
          <th>Order Status</th>
        </tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr>
          <td>',$row['orderLinks'],'</td>
          <td style="text-align:center">$',$row['cost'],'</td>
          <td style="text-align:center">',$row['orderStatus'],'</td>
        </tr>';
}

echo '</table><br>';
```

Apart from that you should switch to PDO / mysqli because the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and to fix potential sql injection problems.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much.  I'm still in the learning process and haven't gotten to looking at PDO/mysqli.  I've heard before to do something different to prevent injections.  Can't I just prevent people from injections by javascript or php functions, to allow users to enter certain characters and use things like stripslashes or preg_replace?

Comment: @denikov No, valid input can also contain characters like `'` or `"` so you always need to use prepared statements or escape your variables before you use them in sql.